# flexslider responsive carousel problems

Tags: javascript, css, drupal-7, flexslider

I need to create a responsive carousel using flexslider. The problem is that one I shrink the browser window below the size of my container, item positions get messed up.

This is a screenshot of the slider on >1200 screen (fine)
[image]

This is a screenshot of the slider on >800 screen (!!)
[image]

My JS init.:

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: true,
    touch: true,
    mousewheel: true,
    itemWidth: 400,         
    prevText: "",
    nextText: ""
    });
```

As you can see in image (2), the third image get chopped off. I want to either reduce the number of visible elements to two when the resolution reaches threshold, and make the images adapt to available space so nothing get chopped off. Ideas?

Comment: Can't you just use css and set the img width to 33%?

Comment: Hi @phil , it seems to reset the width on sliding. Also the parent div containing all items has a width of 1000%, so it wouldn't help.

Comment: I got ya.   Just looked at the Flexslider specs.  What about the itemWidth option that is built in? Can you change that to a percentage based value?

Comment: Or, it seems they have a minimum number and maximum number of items to be shown option.  What if you set both to 3?  minItems, maxItems

Comment: @Phil the value is in form of {ItemWidth: 400;} , so I cannot. And again, the parent element has a width of 1000%, so setting children to 33% wouldn't do much good.

Comment: What about minItems: 3, maxItems: 3?

Comment: Settings those two values and removing itemWidth messed everything up. Setting those two values and leaving itemWidth at 400 created same results as previously (3rd element gets chopped off)

Comment: Ok, last comment.  What about setting itemWidth dynamically based on $(window).width() / 3 ?

You could also re-instantiate Flexslider on $(window).resize() using the updated $(window) width.

Edit:  Or, I guess you'd have to do some math to get the width just right.  It's not actually the window width / 3, but I'm sure you could figure out the slider's "viewport" (as opposed to container) width or whatever...

Comment: Looking at this demo http://flexslider.woothemes.com/carousel-min-max.html it seems the problem is in math used to calculate container width, since in the demo it's not responsive until you reload at wanted screen size.

Answer (score 5):

It's because of `itemWidth` on your flexslider. You should write mediaquery to make the width flexible on respective devices. And before that add this extra script and try.

```
// tiny helper function to add breakpoints
var getGridSize = function() {
  return (window.innerWidth < 600) ? 1 :
         (window.innerWidth < 900) ? 2 : 3;
}

$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: false,
    itemWidth: 200,
    itemMargin: 40,
    minItems: getGridSize(), // use function to pull in initial value
    maxItems: getGridSize(), // use function to pull in initial value
    directionNav: true,
    controlNav: false,
    slideshow: false,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but it looks like this might solve your problem:

http://flexslider.woothemes.com/dynamic-carousel-min-max.html

The min- and max-items settings are set dynamically, based on window width...

A bit messy, but it does work so that no image gets chopped of.